# How do I create loops to join groups of files within a directory?

Tags: files, scripting

I have lots of very large files that take a long time to join manually. They look something like this:

- file_a1.txt
- file_a2.txt
- file_a3.txt
- file_b1.txt
- file_b2.txt
- file_b3.txt
- file_c1.txt
- file_c2.txt
- file_c3.txt
  and so on. How do I join all the a's together, all the b's together and then all the c's using a loop ?

Comment: for x in {a,b,c}; do cat "file_${x}"* > "file_$x_combined"`; done

Comment: @jordanm: (1) Instead of `"file_${x}"*`, you could say simply `"file_$x"*`. (2) Instead of `"file_$x_combined"`, you *must* say `"file_${x}_combined"`, `"file_$x"_combined`, or something equivalent. Your current code tries to evaluate a variable `$x_combined`. (3) Once point #2 is fixed, your code will write files `file_a_combined`, `file_b_combined`, and `file_c_combined`. Then, if the command is run again, it will include ***those files*** in the wildcard. In situations like this, it’s wise to give the new file a name that doesn’t match the pattern of the input files.

Comment: P.S.  There is an extra backtick (\`) in your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that by "joining" you mean concatenating, and not "performing a relational JOIN operation between them using the `join` command".  Furthermore I assume that the filenames follow the pattern `file_XN.txt` where `X` is some single letter and `N` is some number and that all files are located in the current directory.

Concatenation of files is done using the `cat` command, so you would have to call cat with all the "`a`-files", then the "`b`-files", etc., while writing the output to some appropriately named file.

```
for filename in ./file_[a-z]*.txt; do
    # extract the letter
    letter=${filename#*_}     # ./file_XN.txt --> XN.txt
    letter=${letter%[0-9]*}   # XN.txt --> X

    cat "$filename" >>"combined_$letter.txt"
done
```

This would loop over all files and extract the letter from the filename.  The letter would then be used to construct the output filename and the contents of the current file would be appended to that output file.

The data would be appended in the same order as the files would be listed in the directory by default.

Another shorter way of doing it if you're using `bash` and know exactly the letters you want to go through (using `a` through to `t` here):

```
for letter in {a..t}; do
    cat "file_$letter"*.txt >"combined_$letter.txt"
done
```

Here, instead of looping over the filenames, we loop over the letters and for each letter we concatenate all files for that letter in one go.